# Label Text not changing on C++/CLR Windows Forms

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, visual-c++, clr

I am working on a small C++/CLR Windows Forms Project on Visual Studios Community 2019 using .NET Framework 4.0 in which I have a Combo Box and a Label.

The code fragment below works fine:

```
private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
            label1->Text = "comboBox1->Text";
        }
```

But if I add a `Sleep(1000);` after `label1->Text = "comboBox1->Text";`, I expect the label to change before the sleep period, but it changes after the sleep period is over.

In general, the `label1->Text = "comboBox1->Text";` gets executed after whatever is below that line.

For the below code fragment, I want the program to sleep after changing the label1 Text.

```
private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
            label1->Text = "comboBox1->Text";
            Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: That is by design, the label does not repaint itself until the OS tells it to do so.  That can't happen while the UI thread is asleep.  label1->Update() before the sleep hurries that up.  Never sleep the UI thread, always prefer a Timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you mean. To implement this function, you need to use a `timer`. You need to add a `timer` to your WinForm, and then set the Interval value to 1000 in the timer property. You need to use `Start` to start the timer, you could refer to my code.

`this->timer1->Interval = 1000;`

`this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::timer1_Tick);`

`timer1->Start();`

`private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) { label1->Text = comboBox1->Text; }`